# How to update page content after success post in a form without page refresh and not using ajax

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In cshtml file, there is a form and i want to update the data without refresh the whole page only refresh that form.
[After Updation of form user spam count form value image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SYjN.jpg)
I just enter the action method in form tag on which input tag value pass to the controller and update that value but whole page get refreshed but i want to refresh only that form.[Befor Update any value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkiFs.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Ajax Post you can post data without refreshing whole page.

Example :

Html

```
<h2>PostDataForm</h2>
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-header">
    <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
    Form 1
  </div>
 <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="Email1" name="Email1" class="form-control" 
     placeholder="Email address" >
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="BtnForm1" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
   value="Submit" />
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="card mb-3">
 <div class="card-header">
    <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
    Form 2
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="Email2" name="Email2" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Email address" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="BtnForm2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
  value="Submit" />
  </div>
  </div>

 <div class="card mb-3">
<div class="card-header">
    <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
    Form 3
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="Email3" name="Email3" class="form-control" 
  placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="BtnForm3" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
  value="Submit" />
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#BtnForm1").click(function () {
        if ($("#Email1").val() != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/User/PostDataForm1',
               // dataType: 'json',
                data: { email: $("#Email1").val() },
                success: function() {
                    alert("Form 1 submitted successfully!");
                },
                error: function (ex) {

                    alert("ex");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Please Form 1 email address");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Controller

```
  public ActionResult PostDataForm() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostDataForm1(string email) {
        //update your data
        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Similarly write remaining forms post method